# Pass Values to a generic Method dynamically

Tags: java, hibernate, generics, hibernate-criteria

I am using Hibernate and I have Many methods of this type:

```
 public static void modifySchemeEvents(String schmCode, String username) {
        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        Transaction tx = null;
        try {
            tx = session.beginTransaction();
            Criteria cr = session.createCriteria(SchmEventsTable.class);
            cr.add(Restrictions.eq("schmCode", schmCode));
            SchmEventsTable evt = (SchmEventsTable) cr.uniqueResult();
            evt.setLchgUserId(username);
            tx.commit();
        } catch (HibernateException asd) {
            log.debug(asd.getMessage());
            if (tx != null) {
                tx.rollback();
            }
        } finally {
            session.close();
        }
    }
```

This updated the database with the username where schmCode is `<schmCode>` I am attempting to convert to generic so that I do not have to write a separate method for all updates so I have come up with this generic method:

```
public static <T> T getUpdateObject(Class c, Map<String, ?> params) {
        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        Transaction tx = null;
        T value = null;
        try {
            tx = session.beginTransaction();
            Criteria cr = session.createCriteria(c);
            for (Map.Entry<String, ?> entry : params.entrySet()) {
                cr.add(Restrictions.eq(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()));
            }
            value = (T) cr.uniqueResult();
////How to set the values here?***
            tx.commit();
        } catch (HibernateException asd) {
            log.debug(asd.getMessage());
            if (tx != null) {
                tx.commit();
            }
        } finally {
            session.close();
        }
        return value;
    }
```

I am attempting to use it this way:

```
Map<String, String> schemeEventMap = new HashMap();
schemeEventMap.put("schmCode", "CA201");
SchmEventsTable evt = DataOperation.getUpdateObject(SchmEventsTable.class, schemeEventMap);
evt.setLchgUserId(username);
```

This does not update the table like the first method. I am wondering how to pass the parameters in the generic Method Dynamically.

Comment: Create a abstract parent class or interface  for those T-s. Add in abstract  method or interface method updateValues(Map<String, ?> values). Implement this method in all of the child classes. Inside you make a switch or ifelse statements where you check the keys and values and call corresponding methods to set the values.

Comment: Do you have an example I can follow?

Comment: Define a interface parent that has a method setValues(Map<String, ?>).
all the classes you pass to your getUpdateObject must implement this interface. 
in each of the classes the setValues(Map<String, ?>) is implemented like so if(map.containsKey("fieldName")){this.setField(map.get("fieldName"));} for each field.

And in your getUpdateObject, you psdd in s 3rd psrsmeter that is the field value pairs. instead of T you have parent. and you just call object.setValues(fieldValueMap);